# Adjectives that describe the general shape of fishes

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, mathematics, animals

My question has to do with the adjectives one can use to describe the very general shape of a fish if we think of these three axes:

- tail-to-head axis
- back-to-belly axis
- side-to-side axis

**Question 1**

What adjectives shall I use to describe the fishes on these 3 axes?

- tail-to-head axis

  - long vs short
- back-to-belly axis

  - tall vs …
  - deep vs shallow
- side-to-side axis

  - wide vs thin

(I expect you to replace the adjectives "wide", "shallow", "thin", "long", "tall", etc… by appropriate adjectives)

**Question 2**

How can one describe the two extremes of the ratio of the tail-to-head distance over the back-to-belly distance?

- tail-to-head/back-to-belly ratio

  - long vs round

**Question 3**

Can we say that this ratio expresses the "roundness" of the fishes?

Comment: This is addressed [here](http://www.fao.org/docrep/003/f0752e/F0752E03.HTM). Though not answered unequivocally, simply, or adjectivally.

Comment: In my humblest opinion, this question is not in a format optimally suited to the StackExchange Q&A model.  It asks three questions not just one, making it impossible to vote separately. It is somewhat confusing. It assumes that there is something wrong with existing words, or that there must exist special words restricted to fish domain alone.  I would try asking each question separately (but maybe not asking all of them at all), narrowing the scope of each question, and showing prior research or theories or confusions that you have already considered.

Comment: Or asking them of ichthyologists, not language hobbyists.

Comment: @tchrist I understand your point. I think my 3 questions are so small and intimately linked to each others that it was wise to ask them all in one. I don't assume that there is something wrong in the adjectives I suggest. I would like your personal recommendations of what adjectives I should use to describe the shape of fishes. Does it sound good to you to talk about a long and wide fish which is not very tall?

Comment: @JohnLawler Indeed asking this question to ichtyiologist seem a better idea. THe problem is that, I think someone already asked a similar question on Biology.SE and I can't find it anymore. I suspect that it has been deleted. I remember, biologists didn't really welcome this question!

Comment: There may be a reason why. There are an awful lot of kinds of fish, and they don't all fit the same description, nor even fit on the same axes. Take a look, for instance, at [what Fillmore says about flounders](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis-flounder.html) in his second Deixis Lecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, the term that describes the deviation from being a circle is [*eccentricity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_%28mathematics%29). The larger the eccentricity, the more ellipsoidal a circle is. A circle is inherently non-eccentric; its eccentricity is equal to zero, by definition.

But words like "elongated ellipsoid" might describe a long, thin fish, while a rounder fish might be closer to an "oblate spheroid."